# Dynamically changed UIImage width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have UIImage like this with place for UITextField at free white space between red lines at left side:
[image: example]

UIImage real borders bigger than visible part because gesture recognizer linked to this image and it needs to be bigger for more comfortable using with gestures.

Text alignment in text field set to right side. So task is to crop image frame from left side depending on entered text length, when keyboard dismissed after entering text. I used this code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
            ruleImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1,1);
            [ruleImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120 + ruleTextfield.text.length * 15 , ruleImage.frame.size.height)];
}
```

But this code compressed image horizontally, not cropped, and from left to right. So questions:

- how to set anchor point to top (or bottom)right corner?
- what property can I use to crop image?

P.S. also I tried

```
ruleImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
ruleImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopRight;
```

but this properties not solved my problem.

Comment: The tag 'Xcode' is not something relevant here.

Comment: your image is missing. upload it to imgur.com

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ruleImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Comment: now image override textfield. Do I need to draw textfield and image borders at sample in the post to be more clear for you with this question?

Comment: Make it clear what is the "image" and where you want it to appear. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.